# echo "abc 123 " | sed 's/\([0-9][0-9][0-9]\)/\1/'

Tags: unix, sed, scripting

I am learning sed in unix. I need some help. I am trying to understand why

```
echo 123 abc | sed  's/\([0-9][0-9][0-9]\)/\1/' ]
```

does not work when I try to print three numeric letter "123",
but it works when I use

```
echo 123 abc | sed  's/.* \([0-9][0-9][0-9]\).*/\1/'
```

And how can I print "12" instead of "123"?

Please let me know how sed works and where my approach is wrong .

Comment: What is it that you think `s/\([0-9][0-9][0-9]\)/\1/` means?

Comment: In the first example you have an extra `]` at the end of the line. Are you trying to do: `echo 123 abc | sed  's/123/12/'` ?

Answer (score 0):

You probably either want this:

```
echo 123 abc | sed  's/123/12/'
```

or if you want to generalize the `123` by using regex:

```
cho 123 abc | sed  's/\([0-9]\)\([0-9]\)\([0-9]\)/\1\2/g'
```

Comment: You can use the `-r` so you do not need to escape the `()`: `echo 123 abc | sed  -r 's/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])/\1\2/g'`

Comment: Nice! thanks Jotne! BTW, on my mac `-r` is not recognized, I had to use `-E` instead.

Answer (score 0):

In your first command: `([0-9][0-9][0-9])` matches the `123` field and put it in group 1 which you can reference it by `\1`.

So why your first command did not give you `123`? The regex was right, it's just because you are replacing `123` (matched by `[0-9][0-9][0-9]`) with `123` (referenced by `\1`) and it seemed something happened.

And now, you may understand why the second command worked. Since `.` matches any character and `*` means repeat zero or more times, so 
`([0-9][0-9][0-9]).*` matched the whole string and put `123` in group 1.

So you are replacing the whole string with `123` in you second command, and `sed` prints the content in PatternSpace by default.

If you just want to print `12`, just change `([0-9][0-9][0-9])` to `([0-9][0-9])`.

BTW, you can use `[0-9]{3}` instead of `[0-9][0-9][0-9]`.